# Extract a value from input a store it in array

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to take the user input, which is obtained with an event listener, display it on the page, and store the value in an array for further use. However, the array stays empty. Any ideas?

```
let arr = [];
function display() {
    let p = document.querySelector('p');
    let btn = document.querySelector('btn');
    let input = document.querySelector('input').value;
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        p.textContent = input;
        arr.push(input);                         
    });
}
display();
```

Comment: Define "for further use". are you looking to use the array right away, or store it in the browser or db for another day?

Comment: I am looking to store in the array right after is being submited

Answer (score 0):

```
function display() {
  let p = document.querySelector('p');
  let arr = [];
  let btn = document.querySelector('btn');
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let input = document.querySelector('input').value; // <-- move this line here
    p.textContent = input;
    arr.push(input);                         
  });
}
display()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're reading `input` out before the button has an event listener - so the current value (an empty string) will be read. Make sure to declare `input` inside the event listener:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let input = document.querySelector("input").value;
  p.textContent = input;
  arr.push(input);                         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that `document.querySelector('btn')` is not properly selecting the button because there is no such thing as a `btn` element. You'll need to change that to `document.querySelector('button')`. Then, combine that with what the other answers have mentioned -- you also need to capture the input value *inside* the event handler function.

```
let arr = [];
function display() {
  let p = document.querySelector("p");
  let btn = document.querySelector("button");
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let input = document.querySelector("input").value;
    p.textContent = input;
    arr.push(input);
  });
}
display();
```